# Beginner problem in UNIX shell commands and pipes

Tags: shell, unix, pipe

this is material from a course. From my research the code will always begin with the shebang

```
#! /bin/sh
```

And I also figured to solve this I would probably need to use a combinations of

```
wc, tail, grep, head
```

But I am having trouble putting this together. Help would be much appreciated.

```
Write a shell command that processes a file 
that is 200 lines long or more. It outputs the number of those lines within lines 100 through 
199 *inclusive* that contain the character string “hello”.


Write a shell command that outputs the number of lines in the lines range 
100..199  that contain "hello, " but is NOT followed by "world".
```

Comment: Does line counting start at 0 or 1?

Comment: in the first task you meant you need to print only the line numbers of the relevant lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st task

```
head -n 199 $FILE | tail -n 100 | grep "hello" | wc -l
```

2nd task

```
head -n 199 $FILE | tail -n 100 | grep "hello, " | grep -v "hello, world" | wc -l
```